# Django Ajax form submission get 500 Internal Server Error: TypeError at /articles/test_1 get() got an unexpected keyword argument 'id'

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, django

Currently I'm trying to realize "Add comments" funtion for my website through ajax submission. But I always get `500 Internal Server Error` when I submit comments. I checked Chrome console and found it says `"TypeError at /articles/test_1 get() got an unexpected keyword argument 'id'"` (here `test_1` is the slug of the article). I'm confused about this error. Could anyone please help me about this?

My **models.py**:

```
class Article_comments(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Article, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    nicknames = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='UserProfile_nickname')
    comment = models.TextField(max_length=3000)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Article comments'
        verbose_name_plural = verbose_name
        ordering = ['-timestamp']

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}-{}'.format(self.post.article_ti, str(self.nicknames.nickname), self.nicknames.avatar, self.nicknames.qq, self.nicknames.motto, self.nicknames.create_time, self.nicknames.user_url)
```

My **views.py**

```
def article_details(request, slug):
    article_detail = get_object_or_404(Article, slug=slug) 
    comments = Article_comments.objects.filter(post=article_detail).order_by('-timestamp')
    paginator_comment = Paginator(comments, per_page=5)
    page_var = 'page'
    page = request.GET.get(page_var, 1)

    try:
        sets = paginator_comment.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        sets = paginator_comment.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        sets = paginator_comment.page(paginator_comment.num_pages)

# Here is the ajax code:
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.is_ajax():
            user = request.user
            usr_nc = UserProfile.objects.filter(usr=user)
            cmt_user = usr_nc
            cmt_art_id = request.POST.get('article_id')
            cmt_body = request.POST.get('body')
            article = request.POST.get(id=cmt_art_id)
            slug = slug
            comments = Article_comments.objects.create(nicknames=cmt_user, comment=cmt_body, post=article)
            comments.save()
            return JsonResponse({'msg': 'Comments successfully submitted!'})

    article_detail.view_sum()
    return render(request, 'article_detail.html', {'article_detail':article_detail, 'comments':comments, 'sets':sets, 'page_var':page_var})
```

My **app/urls.py**:

```
path('articles/<str:slug>', article_details, name='article_url')
```

My templete's ajax code is:

```
$('#Add_reply').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var coms=$('#main_comments_area').val()
    if (coms == 0){
        alert('Please enter your comments!')
        return;
    }
    var art_id=$('#main_comments_area').data('article_id');
    var usr_name=$('#main_comments_area').data('cmt_usr');
    var csrf=$('#main_comments_area').data('csrf');
    var urlslg=$('#main_comments_area').data('slug');
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:urlslg,
        data:{
            user:usr_name,
            cmt_art_id:art_id,
            cmt_body:coms,
            csrfmiddlewaretoken:csrf
        },

        beforSend:function () {
            alert("Sending ...")
        },
        success:function () {
            alert('Success!')
        },
        error:function (data) {
            alert('Error：'+data.msg)
        }
    })

})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error happens inside this block of `if`:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    ...
    ...
    article = request.POST.get(id=cmt_art_id)
    ...
```

Because `request.POST` is a dictionary like object, when you use `request.POST.get` you can't pass `id` as keyword argument (`id=...`).

So, the question is: what do you want to accomplish on that line? I suppose you want to retrieve the article from the DB, in which you should be doing:

```
article = Article.objects.get(id=cmt_art_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should have shown the full traceback, which would have made it easier to see where the error comes from. I presume it is here:

```
article = request.POST.get(id=cmt_art_id)
```

You probably meant:

```
article = Article.objects.get(id=cmt_art_id)
```